# VBA code to look for a value, copy next to it, paste directly or by leaving blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA coding, I hope someone could help me.

I am trying to code a loop to find a specific integer value (called "TrialNumber") on Column A, check the value on the same row of Column G and paste the value to another workbook. The trick is if the value is less than 100, I want to leave that amount of blank cells instead of pasting. The data looks like this:

```
Column A ... Column G
101          310
101          385
102          300
102          355
102          290
102          3
102          325
103          365
103          360
...          ...
```

Let's take 102, I want the output in another workbook looks like this:

```
Column A
300
355
290
blank cell
blank cell
blank cell
325
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have any of your code?

Comment: I have some code, but they are irrelevant. They are for entering trial number to the input box, creating sheets, formatting etc. I am stuck in this if/while loop issue for days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this macro to your original data sheet. It assumes that the active worksheet is the data sheet (the sheet with trial numbers).

```
Public Sub ProcessTrialNumbers()
    Dim rSource As Range ' Col A
    Dim rTrialNo As Range ' current cell with trial number in Col A
    Dim iMatchedValue As Integer ' matching value in Col G
    Dim rTarget As Range ' Col in shtTarget where values will pasted
    Dim iTargetRowIndex As Integer ' pointer to which row in target col I want the next value to be pasted
    Const SWITCH_VALUE As Integer = 100 ' anything below this will switch on the blank rows logic
    
    'define the Column A range to loop through
    'there are different ways to do this - below is just one example
    Set rSource = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    ' BEWARE: current region includes all contiguous cells
    ' you can also use:
    Set rSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A9")
    
    'define the column to which values will be pasted
    Set rTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
    
    iTargetRowIndex = 1
    
    For Each rTrialNo In rSource
    
        ' we can reference Column G by offset - it's just one way to get matching Col G value
        ' this way is not pretty and will break if anyone changes the spreadsheet
        ' but it serves as a quick example
        iMatchedValue = rTrialNo.Offset(0, 6).Value
        
        ' either paste the value or move up iTargetRowIndex to skip rows
        If iMatchedValue >= SWITCH_VALUE Then
            rTarget(iTargetRowIndex, 1).Value = iMatchedValue
            iTargetRowIndex = iTargetRowIndex + 1
        Else
            iTargetRowIndex = iTargetRowIndex + iMatchedValue
        End If

    Next rTrialNo
End Sub
```